# Installing ODOO8 (OPENERP)

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I would like to install Odoo 8 (OpenERP) on my Ubuntu 14.04 system I had to follow a tutorial to install Odoo but when I run this command it shows me these errors:

```
root@Nema:/# su odoo 
odoo@Nema:/$ openerp-server 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/openerp-server", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: qrcode
odoo@Nema:/$
```

how to solve this problem
Help me please ??

Comment: retagging for odoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a library. Install it with pip, apt-get or any other way to install a package.

You'll probably need sudo to install the package.

**apt-get**

> apt-get install python-qrcode

**pip**

> pip install qrcode